# What are the differences between Windows Overlapped IO, Registered IO (RIO) and IoRing?

Tags: windows, performance, winapi, winsock

The main difference seems to be in their focus. Registered IO is network related and IoRing (file) storage related. That said, both seem to follow pretty much the same concept of using queues to minimise system call overhead. This raises the secondary question of why there is no unified solution for minimising system call overhead like io_uring for Linux.

Overlapped IO, on the other hand, can do both networking and file IO but seems to be somewhat bound by system call overhead. Still, I got the impression that most of the time Overlapped IO is presented as the de facto standard for doing performance oriented (network) IO on Windows even though RIO is being available since Windows 8 (which is over 10 years).

Especially further comparison with respect to performance (e.g. when and how buffer copies can be avoided) would be appreciated.

Comment: *"This raises the secondary question of why there is no unified solution like io_uring for Linux."* - That's actually backwards. There **is** a unified solution in Windows: Overlapped I/O. As far as the kernel goes, *all* I/O is asynchronous. The *"unified solution"* in Linux is literally just an attempt to simulate asynchronous I/O on top of a kernel that doesn't know async. Hardly a surprise to anyone that [CVE](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=io_uring)'s are starting to pile up.

Comment: Should have been more clear about this: I meant a "unified solution" for reducing system call overhead of all IO. From my point of view Overlapped IO does not seem to do this.

Comment: Are you asking about optimizing performance or optimization of an arbitrary metric, like system call count?

Comment: In the case of Overlapped IO mainly system call count comes to my mind, yes. But also stuff like when and how its possible to consistently avoid additional copies from kernel space to user space buffers - if this is at all possible. However, the addition of IoRing to the mix of Windows IO APIs made me question what I already thought to know about all of this, so any kind of comparison would be appreciated. 

Windows IO seems to be a nebulous set of APIs, with most of the internet focusing on Overlapped IO, ignoring the alternatives.

Comment: RIO provides increased performance by working with pre-locked buffers,fixed sized completion queues and reduced user mode to kernel mode transitions.

Comment: Overlapped I/O uses the application of overlapping model to notify the buffer for receiving and sending, and the system directly uses the data. If an application posts a 10KB buffer to receive data and the data has reached the socket, the data will be directly copied to the posted buffer.

Comment: However, for blocking, select, WSAAsyncSelect, WSAEventSelect and other models, when data arrives and is copied to the Per Socket Buffer, the application will be notified of the number of bytes that can be read by the system. After the application calls the receive function, the data is copied from the single socket buffer to the application buffer. This reduces a copy from the I/O buffer to the application buffer, which is the difference.